# Encrypt data with X509 certificate's private key in UWP

Tags: c#, encryption, uwp, x509certificate2

I'm displaying to the user every available certificates in his personal store, fetched with the following method :

```
public List<X509Certificate2> GetPersonalCertificates()
{
    var certificates = new List<X509Certificate2>();
    using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

        foreach (var certificate in store.Certificates)
        {
            if (certificate != null && certificate.HasPrivateKey)
            {
                certificates.Add(certificate);
            }
        }
    }

    return certificates;
}
```

When the user select one of those certificates, a sample file is loaded and given to the following method :

```
public byte[] EncryptFile(X509Certificate2 certificate, byte[] fileToEncrypt)
{
    if (certificate == null || hashToSign == null) return null;

    byte[] encryptedFile = null;
    try
    {
        using (var privateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
        {
            encryptedFile = privateKey.Encrypt(hashToSign, System.Security.Cryptography.RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Error management
    }

    return encryptedFile;
}
```

This method is supposed to encrypt the data with the RSA private key using the SHA256 algorithm, but it keeps falling into the catch statement.

The error that I get depends on the certificate that I use :

- When I use a certificate registered in the user's personal store :

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException:
>
> Invalid parameter
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(SafeNCryptKeyHandle
>   key, Byte[] input, AsymmetricPaddingMode paddingMode, Void*
>   paddingInfo, EncryptOrDecryptAction encryptOrDecrypt)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(Byte[] data,
>   RSAEncryptionPadding padding, EncryptOrDecryptAction encryptOrDecrypt)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.Encrypt(Byte[] data,
>   RSAEncryptionPadding padding)
>
> at *My method*

- When I use a certificate from a USB key :

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException:
>
> The requested operation is not supported
>
> at Security.Cryptography.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(SafeNCryptKeyHandle
>   key, Byte[] input, AsymmetricPaddingMode paddingMode, Void*
>   paddingInfo, EncryptOrDecryptAction encryptOrDecrypt)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(Byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding, EncryptOrDecryptAction
>   encryptOrDecrypt)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.Encrypt(Byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding)
>
> at *My method*

I've also tried the private key's **SignData** method, resulting in the same exceptions :

```
encryptedFile = privateKey.SignData(hashToSign, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

Am I missing something ?

Please note that, as I'm working in an UWP application, I can only access [some of the System.Security namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185488.aspx).

Comment: Have you tried using OaepSha1 instead of OaepSha256? Trying to narrow down where the problem might be.

Comment: I got the same results with OaepSha1 and Pkcs1, unfortunately.

Comment: @ThomasFerro You should use PublicKey to encrypt something and PrivateKey to decrypt.

Comment: @pepi I'm tying to digitally sign data here, so the point is not to make these data unreadable. Instead, the goal is to be able to prove that a given user signed the document by using his public key to decrypt the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my issues, it was due to these two mistakes :

First, the encryption method to use here isn't **Encrypt** but **SignData**, since I want to electronically sign the data.

Second, in order to make a valid signature, the certificate needs to contain the **Non-Repudation** extension. To check that, I've added this method :

```
private bool _canUsingCertificateForSignData(X509ExtensionCollection extensions)
{
    if (extensions != null)
    {
        foreach (var ext in extensions)
        {
            if (ext.GetType().Equals(typeof(X509KeyUsageExtension)))
            {
                if (((X509KeyUsageExtension)ext).KeyUsages.HasFlag(X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I now fetch the certificates using the following :

```
public List<X509Certificate2> GetPersonalCertificates()
{
    var certificates = new List<X509Certificate2>();
    using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

        foreach (var certificate in store.Certificates)
        {
            if (certificate != null && certificate.HasPrivateKey && _canUsingCertificateForSignData(certificate.Extensions))
            {
                certificates.Add(certificate);
            }
        }
    }

    return certificates;
}
```

One thing that I still don't understand is why the **SignData** method doesn't throw any exception and did sign the data when the certificate is fetched from a *pfx* file and not from the store.

Comment: It's possible that the key in the store had some permissions/restrictions applied which either didn't get exported to the PFX, or the PFX was from before the permissions got set that way.